# consulta de cualquier dato que no se encuentra en la tabla en mysql

Tags: mysql

como hago para que salga esto

```
declare monto double;
set monto =500.00;

select '','',monto,'','' from [que tabla iría aquí]
```

y el resultado que sea de la siguiente manera por que lo quiero unir a una consulta como un resultado

```
[vacio] [vacio] [500.00] [vacio] [vacio]
```

en 4gl lo podia hacer pero en mysql no se como hacerlo tal vez una tabla maestra o temp no se

Comment: No entiendo, no es esto `select NULL, NULL, 200, NULL, NULL UNION ....` lo que quieres hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Ayudaria mucho que nos dieras un poco mas de informacion sobre la duda que tienes, lo que interpreto es que necesitas que la consulta te regrese solo la columna monto.

En MySQL solo necesitarias el siguiente query:

```
SELECT monto FROM nombre_tabla;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si logro entender, lo que quieres hacer es generar columnas vacías a los lados de una que ya tienes el dato, verdad?. Si es así lo que debes usar es **null** para la columna que quieres reflejar como vacía.

```
DECLARE monto double;
SET monto =500.00;
SELECT null, null, monto, null, null;
```

No necesitarías especificar tabla alguna, es simplemente una sentencia.
No logro entender el fin de tu pregunta, pero con ello respondería a tu duda.